# Brother DCP-J140W

Tags: brother, scanning

We have this printer in the office, three computers are hooked up to it using wireless. However, when we try and scan only 2 of the 3 printers show up in the menu on the printer. But, if I turn off one of those computers the third one will appear in the drop down menu. Does this printer only support 2 computers on line at once? If so, is there a way to change which ones show up? If it does allow more than 2- how do I add computer #3. Of course, the one that doesn't show up is mine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Install brother printer drivers and see:

```
sudo apt-get install brother-lpr-drivers-ac brother-lpr-drivers-bh7 brother-lpr-drivers-common brother-lpr-drivers-extra brother-lpr-drivers-laser brother-lpr-drivers-laser1
```

** remove the `not available` packages for the version of ubuntu.